# Problem with JWT verification in Next.js and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, next.js, jwt

I am trying to make protected routes in Next.js using middleware:

```
import { type NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { verifyAuth } from '@helpers/auth/verifyJWT';

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/dash', '/auth/:path*'],
};

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const verifiedToken = await verifyAuth(req).catch((err) => {
    console.error(err.message);
  });

  if (!verifiedToken) {
    if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/dash')) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/auth/login', req.url));
    } else {
      return NextResponse.next();
    }
  } else {
    if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/auth')) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/dash', req.url));
    } else {
      return NextResponse.next();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is verifyAuth method:

```
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

import { jwtVerify } from 'jose';
import { USER_TOKEN, getJwtSecretKey } from '../constatns';

interface UserJwtPayload {
  jti: string;
  iat: number;
}

export class AuthError extends Error {}

export async function verifyAuth(req: NextRequest) {
  const token = req.cookies.get(USER_TOKEN)?.value;

  if (!token) throw new AuthError('Missing user token ');

  try {
    const verified = await jwtVerify(
      token,
      new TextEncoder().encode(getJwtSecretKey()),
    );
    return verified.payload as UserJwtPayload;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new AuthError('Your token has expired.');
  }
}
```

Problem is that I always get the message: Token is expired.

I am using Spring Boot for backend part, here is my SpringSecurity part for signing token:

```
  public String generateToken(
      Map<String, Object> extraClaims,
      UserDetails userDetails
  ) {
    return Jwts
        .builder()
        .setClaims(extraClaims)
        .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
        .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
        .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 24))
        .signWith(getSignInKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
        .compact();
  }


  private Key getSignInKey() {
    byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET_KEY);
    return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
  }
```

So I tried many libraries to code/encode my secret key in the Nextjs app but same error.
I am not sure how to do it.
Is there any other solution?

Comment: Where do you get the "Token is expired"? Is it at the `catch` method in `verifyAuth` function? Maybe the _secret verification_ process fails, but you've set the error to show message "Your token has expired" so you get that?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I meant 'Your token has expired'. It happens in the TryCatch block in the verifyAuth function.

Comment: Console.log the error, before throwing the AuthError you create, you may discover it's not a problem with the expiration, but rather something else like secret verification.

Comment: This is error I get :
 [JWSSignatureVerificationFailed: signature verification failed] {
  code: 'ERR_JWS_SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION_FAILED',
  name: 'JWSSignatureVerificationFailed',
  message: 'signature verification failed'
}
Also, If I put inside the TextEndcoder() secret_key manually, without fetching from .env, I get same error

Comment: Okay, this means that it's not the expiration, but the SECRET string that you use sign the token with. 
For development purposes, on Backend, try signing the token with some basic `testtest` string. Use the same string on the FE for verifying.


The secret has to match on FE and BE, unfortunately I'm no spring-boot master, but I'm guessing it's the issue with what data type /string is actually signing the token.